# coordinates in an area tag

Tags: html, area, coordinate

So I've started a web design course about 4 months ago, it's going smoothly and I'm really enjoying it. I'm trying to learn more in my own time and found  tag while searching for something similair.

I don't fully understand it, but I think I get the grasp of it, so basically I'm asking if what I think the cords do is correct.

coords="x1,y1, x2,y2"

Does that create a box, which I can then use a  so when it's pressed linked to another page?

Comment: I guess you are reffering to `area` tag. Yes , you can create a box, link, etc. See more info here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused. 
This function **won't perform any doing**. In fact, all that is a 'string'. Meaning, if you refer to cords, you will just find 'x1,y1, x2,y2' as the value.

If you're interested in linking content, use 'a' tags. Also, if you'd like to create a nice box, you're going to need some styling knowledge. Remember, as a web designer you create content for the web developer to put together. If you're looking into making the sites, look for a course in 'Web Development'.